# Open one form from another form in a different project

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I've got one application which has the following projects inside of it:

- APP.ABC.Main
- APP.ABC.Reporting
- APP.ABC.Interface

In my APP.ABC.Main project, I have a main form which needs to open a report in APP.ABC.Reporting.  I've already set up a reference to APP.ABC.Reporting inside of the APP.ABC.Main project.  But I can't figure out how to open the Reporting form from the Main project.

I've got this set up:

```
private void tileSQLAcct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Open up ReportTest.cs form in APP.ABC.Reporting.
   
}
```

No matter what I try, Intellisense always turns it red.  I'm kind of new to this, what can I try next?

Comment: `var form = new APP.ABC.Reporting.ReportTest();`? Hard to tell without seeing the namespace and whatnot.

Comment: A Form is just a class, so new one up just like any object. Then call `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the form you want to open is declared as `public`. Otherwise it will not be visible from outside its own assembly.

Now you should be able to open it from another project or assembly with (if the form resides in the namespace `APP.ABC.Reporting`):

```
var frm = new APP.ABC.Reporting.ReportTest();
frm.Show(); // or .ShowDialog();
```

Or with a using-statement at the top of the code file

```
using APP.ABC.Reporting;
```

you can open it with

```
var frm = new ReportTest();
frm.Show(); // or .ShowDialog();
```

Note that a `Form` is a class. First you must instantiate it, i.e. create an object from it with `new ReportTest()`. Then you can call the form-specific `Show` or `ShowDialog` routines. The difference between them is that after calling `Show` the calling routine continues, whereas with `ShowDialog` the calling routine waits until the form is closed before it resumes.

`ShowDialog` also returns a result that you can evaluate:

```
if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    var result = frm.MyResult; // Where `MyResult` is supposed to be a public member.
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  I have no idea why that was so hard for me to figure out.  :o)